# Using vispy canvas within pyqtgaph viewbox

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, vispy

I am using [`pyqtgraph.ImageView`](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/widgets/imageview.html) to visualize data.

I need to smooth transition in my image with `vispy` like in this photo:
[image: smooth transition]

Do you know any way to get this kind of result with `pyqtgraph` or any way to integrate `vispy` canvas into `pyqtgraph.ImageView`?

Comment: VisPy maintainer here, there is likely no way to put vispy inside a pyqtgraph visualization. You might be able to put them next to each other, but in the same widget is unlikely. I could be wrong though.